# JavaScript date manipulation, 'date' parameter passed to function

Tags: javascript, datetime

Trying to understand why you would have a parameter in a JS function which hasn't been passed in at the function call, or been previously declared anywhere in the script.

You can see the parameter 'date' in the `checkAvailable` function here...

```
var dateToday = new Date();

$('#visit').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: checkAvailable,
    minDate: dateToday
});

var unavailableDates = ["19-10-2012","1-2-2013","15-10-2012"];

function checkAvailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) != -1) {

        return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
    } else {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0 && day != 6)];
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why that parameter exists?

Thanks!

Here is all the code [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Virtual/gvz3P/)

Comment: If `date` is never passed in, that function will throw a `TypeError` because `date` will be undefined. Are you sure that the parameter isn't passed in via `bind`, for example?

Comment: Just added the link to jsfiddle you can see it working there, and no TypeError in the console....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter will be passed in when it is called. In the example usage you linked it might look like no parameters are passed in, but in fact the function isn't called at that point. The function is only passed into the library, which will then call it later from another place, and pass in a date to check. You can see this for yourself [in the source code of the library](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/datepicker.js#L1795):

```
beforeShowDay.apply( ( inst.input ? inst.input[ 0 ] : null ), [ printDate ] )
```

The `apply` method is where the function is actually called, and the values in the `[ printDate ]` array are passed in as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

That link shows it's a callback function for jQuery UI Datepicker. The function call happens in jQuery UI Datepicker source code:

[image: Fiddle]

Here's a simplified example:

```js
var callback = function (a, b, c) {
   console.log(a, b, c);
}

callback.apply(null, ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a function callback so it will be called somewhere by jquery and the parameter will be only available by then